# Kafka broker client on Websphere unable to access JKS file

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, websphere, kafka-consumer-api, jks

I am trying to run Kafka producer client to publish some message to kafka broker. I have given the path to Keystore/Trust store along with Password. I was able to send the message to the broker when i deployed this on Apache tomcat. However when i tried to deploy the same application on websphere, i get error "Failed to load SSL keystore". I have given those directories read/write/execute permission. Is there something with websphere that needs different configuration / settings ?

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to load SSL keystore /home/avaya/tcr/uc-ivr-nar-dev.dbplatform.portal.com.jks of type JKS
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslEngineBuilder.createSSLContext(SslEngineBuilder.java:160)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslEngineBuilder.<init>(SslEngineBuilder.java:102)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.configure(SslFactory.java:93)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslChannelBuilder.configure(SslChannelBuilder.java:71)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to load SSL keystore /home/avaya/tcr/uc-ivr-nar-dev.dbplatform.portal.com.jks of type JKS
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslEngineBuilder$SecurityStore.load(SslEngineBuilder.java:289)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslEngineBuilder.createSSLContext(SslEngineBuilder.java:142)
        ... 40 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/avaya/tcr/uc-ivr-nar-dev.dbplatform.portal.com.jks
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:96)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:114)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:119)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:226)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:372)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:418)
        at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:395)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:163)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslEngineBuilder$SecurityStore.load(SslEngineBuilder.java:282)
        ... 41 more
```

Comment: Based on the UnixException, it looks like this is happening below WebSphere, at the JVM / OS level, so there's not likely to be a WebSphere configuration that will fix this. I would double check that the file path and name are correct. I see that you mentioned the permissions, check that the permissions are correct for the user account that WebSphere is running under as well.

Comment: Thank you , yes you are correct. The issue was with the VM having Open JDK running, and it did not like JKS keystore file. I changed the format to PKCS12 and it picket it up.

Answer (score 1):

Open JDK for some reason does not like JKS keystore files. Converted to PCKS12 format and it worked. Nothing to do with websphere container.